# Changes made in C++ code of NDK are not reflected in apk

Tags: android, c++, shell, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am having multiple c++ files in my cocos2d-x project for android.
When I make any changes in the c++ code and then save the file. Then on running I get in console:

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: game_shared <= MyClassName.cpp
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libgame.so
```

As a proof that the code is compiling and there is no mistake in the setup.
but, there is no change in the apk reflected as desired.

So I guess it is picking the binary from somewhere else and not the fresh compiled one.
Where can I check/rectify to ensure it to take the correct binary file.
P.S: I am using Mac
any help/suggestion appreciated

Cheers!

Comment: Do you use ADT bundle, or Android builder, or maybe you set up your Eclipse manually?

Comment: Found it... the 2 locations were one in workspace and another one in the place where the original code was placed. While the code compiled kept the libgame.so file in the code location, and eclipse was picking it up from workspace. For those who get stuck in such problem in future. delete the workspace project(of course backup). and then reimport to eclipse from scratch. and this time while importing deselect the checkbox of "copy to workspace"

Comment: That seems a bit excessive.  Just recopy it to the needed place, or work with the copy in the workspace.